# What is the right time for reading morning and evening duas ?

Tags: dua

Can we read morning duas after fajar prayer and can we read evening duas after maghrib prayer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definitive answer on the **preferred** time of morning and evening supplications, as there is a scholarly difference of opinions. Whichever opinion you decide to follow will be fine.

The first opinion is:

- Morning supplications start from Fajr adhān time till sunrise.
- Evening supplications start from 'Asr adhān time till sunset.

This is based on the following verse:

> فَاصْبِرْ عَلَىٰ مَا يَقُولُونَ وَسَبِّحْ بِحَمْدِ رَبِّكَ قَبْلَ طُلُوعِ الشَّمْسِ وَقَبْلَ الْغُرُوبِ
>
> So be patient, [O Muhammad], over what they say and exalt [ Allah ] with praise of your Lord before the rising of the sun and before its setting,
>
> <sup>— [Surat Qaf 50:39](https://quran.com/50/39/)</sup>

and additionally on the verse:

> فَاصْبِرْ إِنَّ وَعْدَ اللَّهِ حَقٌّ وَاسْتَغْفِرْ لِذَنبِكَ وَسَبِّحْ بِحَمْدِ رَبِّكَ بِالْعَشِيِّ وَالْإِبْكَارِ
>
> So be patient, [O Muhammad]. Indeed, the promise of Allah is truth. And ask forgiveness for your sin and exalt [ Allah ] with praise of your Lord in the evening and the morning.
>
> <sup>— [Surat Ghafir [40:55]](https://quran.com/40/55/)</sup>

The second opinion is:

- Morning supplications extend till Dhuha (about a half-hour before Dhuhr adhān time).
- Evening supplications extend till one-third of the night  (one-third between 'Isha and Fajr adhān times).

This is based on multiple hadiths about supplications during the night, out of which is one about reciting during the night the [last two verses of Surat al-Baqara](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/6/306), and [Surat al-Ikhlās](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/731350).

Comment: JazakAllah Khair.